# How to print the current directory of the docker image which is running in a centOS7 OS from windows docker desktop

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running a docker file which creates a image in centOS machine. I am spinning the container in windows machine by running docker desktop for windows.

I want to print/see the directory or folders in the centOS machine where the docker installs java and other softwares which it installs from the docker commands.

Comment: There are several tools I would suggest. [Dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive) can be used to explore what files are added in each layer. You can use `docker run -it <image> bash` to get an interactive shell to explore your container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the above command has served my purpose.